# Two Lists: One Dictionary - Insert item(s) from one list (values) into keys within a dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, arcpy

(*Note: this employs ESRI arcpy.Describe*)

I have an empty dictionary, say it's called **file_dict**.

I have two lists: 1. One is the list of items of file types I'll use as keys called **typeList**.
 2. The second is a list of files in a folder, called **fileList**.

I am able to:
 Get **typeList** into the dictionary as keys.

```
file_dict.keys()
[u'Layer', u'DbaseTable', u'ShapeFile', u'File', u'TextFile', u'RasterDataset']
```

I need help with:
Using comparisons that check the following: (pseudocoded)

```
FOR each file in fileList:
    CHECK the file type 
''' using arcpy.Describe -- I have a variable already called desc - it is how I got typeList '''
    IF file is a particular type (say shapefile):
        INSERT that value from fileList into a list within the appropriate typeList KEY in file_dict
    ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

My desired output for file_dict would be:

```
    >>> file_dict
    {
u'Layer': ['abd.lyr', '123.lyr'], u'DbaseTable': ['ABD.dbf'], 
u'ShapeFile': ['abc.shp', '123.shp'], u'File': ['123.xml'], 
u'TextFile': ['ABC.txt', '123.txt'], 
u'RasterDataset': ['ABC.jpg', '123.TIF']
}
```

Note: I would like to avoid zipping. (I get it's easier but...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using simple Python script then this would help

```
# Input
file_list = ['abd.lyr', '123.lyr', 'ABD.dbf', 'abc.shp', '123.shp', '123.xml', 
            'ABC.jpg', '123.TIF', 'ABC.txt',  '123.txt'
            ]

# Main code
file_dict = {} #dict declaration


case = {
    'lyr': "Layer",
    'dbf': "DbaseTable",
    'shp': "ShapeFile",
    'xml': "File",
    'txt': "TextFile",
    'jpg': "RasterDataset",
    'TIF': "RasterDataset",
} # Case declaration for easy assignment


for i in file_list:
    file_dict.setdefault(case[i.split(".")[-1]], []).append(i) # appending files to the case identified using setdefault method.

print (file_dict)

# Output
# {'Layer': ['abd.lyr', '123.lyr'], 'DbaseTable': ['ABD.dbf'], 'ShapeFile': ['abc.shp', '123.shp'], 'File': ['123.xml'], 'RasterDataset': ['ABC.jpg', '123.TIF'], 'TextFile': ['ABC.txt', '123.txt']}
```

I hope this helps and counts!